# C++ dlsym Pointer Function Problems

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface

I am calling a function from shared object (a.so) inside another shared object with JNI interface (b.so). I loaded a.so using **dlopen** and mapped function using **dlsym**.

Here is a part of Code:

```
int (*pTestCall)(char* szMsgOut);

 //OPEN SHARED OBJECT AND CREATE A HANDLER
handle = dlopen (filename, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

 //MAP ADRRESS OF FUNCTION INSIDE SHARED OBJECT TO FUNCTION POINTER
*(void **) (&pTestCall) = dlsym(handle, "_ZN7IpsLink9TestCallElllPc");


  int ret = pTestCall(szMsgOut);
```

In log of **a.so** I can see **TestCall** is called and it finished it's job but when it tries to write output to **szMsgOut** buffer it crashes. If I remove output writing to buffer all go OK without any problem.

Can someone Explain what is the problem or why it crashes?

Here is example:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Linux_WrapperLinux_Payment(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jcharArray jMsgOut){
int RetVal = false;
char cLog[1024] = "";
//Get the len of passed buffer
int len = env->GetArrayLength(jMsgOut);
char *szMsgOut;
szMsgOut = (char*) malloc (len);
memset(szMsgOut, 0x00, len);
//Call function
RetVal = TestCallTry(szMsgOut);
// Copy the result out of the C character buffer into a jchar buffer.  This is where we are converting chars to jchars.
jchar *jcharBuffer = (jchar *)calloc(sizeof(jchar), len);
int tempLen = strlen(szMsgOut);
for (int i = 0; i < tempLen; i ++){
    jcharBuffer[i] = (jchar)szMsgOut[i];
}
if(tempLen > 0)
// Copy the result into the jcharArray.
env->SetCharArrayRegion(jMsgOut, 0, len, jcharBuffer);
// Free the jchar buffer
free(jcharBuffer);
free(szMsgOut);
return RetVal;
}

int (*pTestCall)(char* szMsgOut);

int TestCallTry(char *szMsgOut){
void *handle;
char *error;
char filename[150]="";
char LogLocal[5000]="";
sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",path,LIB_LIBRERIA);
logga(filename,true);
logga("Loading LIB",true);
 //OPEN SHARED OBJECT AND CREATE A HANDLER
handle = dlopen (filename, RTLD_LAZY);

*(void **) (&pTestCall) = dlsym(handle, "_ZN7IpsLink9TestCallElllPc");
int ret = pTestCall(szMsgOut);
dlclose(handle);

return ret;

}
```

Function **Java_Linux_WrapperLinux_Payment** calls **TestCallTry**.

Comment: What *is* `szMsgOut`? The problem could be with the argument you pass to the function. Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I have added code in orginal question. Please check and let me know if it is ok for you.

Comment: Still missing information about the function you're getting via `dlsym`. Create a simpler standalone test program without all the JNI stuff and pass a simple string to your function first. Only then put the other code back in again. Did you check if `dlsym` returns a valid pointer in the first place?

Comment: As wrote in the question, with the pointer of dlsym I am able to call function of shared object. Problem comes when _ZN7IpsLink9TestCallElllPc tries to write something to buffer szMsgOut (using memcpy , strcat).

Comment: How much memory do you allocate for `szMsgOut`? How much do you write to it? How do you write to the buffer (more specifically)? And what is `_ZN7IpsLink9TestCallElllPc`? Is it a non-static member function of a class?

Comment: The Sizeof the buffer szMsgOut is 4000. I write to using memcpy (also tried with Strcat). I am just writing "TEST". Yes, it is non static member function of class._ZN7IpsLink9TestCallElllPc it does nothing except write "TEST" string in output buffer szMsgOut .

Comment: Well then you have *undefined behavior*. Even if the function does nothing with any other class member, it still needs an instance of the class to be called. In fact it could be that the `this` pointer is passed to the member function as a hidden first argument, and by writing you the pointer you overwrite the "object" the member function think its using. Don't ever call a non-static member function if you don't have an actual object to call it on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just created a static function and it solved the problem.